# How to delete bot direct messages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, long story short I was making a bot that's supposed to send a direct message to a user after a command was executed, then wait a bunch of time before deleting it

It works fine and all now, but for a bit of time it didn't, and while I did some testing, my dms with that bot have been flooded with test messages

Is there any command I could add to delete every old messages that this bot sent to my dms ?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a `censor` command that calls [`purge_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.purge_from) on the channel it's invoked from.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def censor(ctx, limit: int= 100):
    await bot.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, 
                         check=lambda message: message.author == bot.user,
                         limit=limit)
```