# Python bot delete messages

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How to make bot delete xx messages. example `!clear xx` and `!clear xx @user`

```
If i use `!clear xx` it should delete xx message.
If i use `!clear xx @user` it should delete xx message of User tagged.
```

Comment: Is `xx` a number?

Comment: yes xx is a number like 1 to 100

Comment: Use `Client.purge_from`. [See a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624082/how-to-delete-bot-direct-messages/51624473#51624473)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  i tried that code its nothing happening no error message.

Comment: Did you change it to accept an author argument to be the person whose messages should be deleted? The linked question is getting the bot to delete its own messages.

Comment: No just copied full code and tried do i need to edit something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51624082/how-to-delete-bot-direct-messages/51624473#51624473) as a starting point:

```
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from datetime import datetime

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True)  # Like the properties of a Permissions object
async def censor(ctx, limit: int, target: discord.User = None):
    check = (lambda message: message.author.id == target.id) if target else None
    try:
        await bot.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, 
                             check=check, 
                             limit=limit)
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await bot.say("I don't have permission to do that")

@censor.error
async def censor_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You don't have permissions")
```

Note that [`purge_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.purge_from) requires a bot account.

Comment: You can use the `has_permissions` check, and then define an error handler to check the user permissions.  For the bot permissions you can either check your own permissions in the body, or catch `discord.Forbidden` when you call `purge_from`

Comment: @Bosen You can only use error handlers for `CommandError`s, and it's subclasses (All of which are errors raised before the coroutine you write is executed).  I'll add an example to my answer

Comment: `has_permissions` works similarly to a [`Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions) object.  `administrator` is a very highly ranked position, so it's possible that you're not actually giving it.  Try with something inconsequential like `read_messages`.

Comment: Is not possible to make this `commands.CheckFailure` error response works for `!censor` command only without touching main `on_command error`

Comment: @Bosen No.  [`on_command_error` is always invoked afterwards as a catch-all](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.error).  I'd recommend against handling `CheckFailure` in `on_command_error`, because it's difficult to know which check is failing if you have many checks across many commands.

Comment: Ok what is best way to add different error response for same `commands.CheckFailure` in `on_command_error` or in commands.

Comment: @Bosen Writing a `Command.error` for each of the commands that could raise `CheckFailure`, like `@censor.error`.

Comment: I think adding `commands.CheckFailure` to all commands will be difficult so i need to edit entire files. I already have 1 `commands.CheckFailure`  in `on_command_error`  just i need a  different response for 3 commands `!clear` and `!kick` and `!ban`

Comment: @Bosen You should be able to get the command with `ctx.command` inside the error handler.

Comment: can i get a sample how to add like that. so i can do for all commands which i need different error response ?.

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question, so that others can find the answer in the future, and in case my solution doesn't work and you want others to see it.

Comment: Ok i created a new question.